# Drupal 6 how do I display a view in a panel as content

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, panels

I have a Drupal 6.17 install with Views and Panels2

Im only new to these modules.

how do I get a view to display as content in one of the panel regions?

I have the panels setup and when I select to load content I dont see the view as an option.

do I need to do something to make the view a node?

Ive setup the view page and block, still no success.

Comment: oops, I think I just found it, its listed under Miscallenous and not a node when selecting the content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to enable Content Panes / View Panes (forget the name of the sub-module) then a new View display type is available to you: Content Panes.

You can also use Views blocks to drop in, but I've found it easier to work with Panes.